# If-else shorthand in ejs template?

Tags: javascript, express, if-statement, conditional-statements, ejs

Below is the code from EJS file which i am rendering but i am not able figure out the correct syntax for the if statement shorthand.

Here "cchoice" is the object that i am passing while rendering and it is working if i remove the if statement, hence there is no problem in getting its value.

```
<h1>Welcome,
    <%= cchoice %>
</h1>
<% cchoice =='dog' ? <p>good choice</p> : <p>cool!</p> %>
```

The error i am getting is :

SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in /views/new.ejs while compiling ejs

Suggest the correct syntax for the above shorthand for if statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `<%-` and surround the HTML with quote:

```
<%- cchoice =='dog' ? '<p>good choice<p>' : '<p>cool!</p>' %>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: @GavishKumar you can tick mark the answer please if it was helpful to you